# Remove dots below required stars in Wordpress checkout-form

Tags: php, wordpress, css, woocommerce

It is never too late to learn. Im very suprised to see some little dots below the all required stars in my Wordpress checkout-form. Any idea how to remove them - prefered with CSS?

**Here the HTML code**

```
<label for="billing_address_1" class="">Street address <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
```

**And an image**

[image]

Comment: Post your entire code in a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It is the <abbr> tag that does it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works fine also in newer Browsers. It seems that firefox and chrome switched `text-decoration` instead of `border`. So only `border: none !important;` is not enough.

```
abbr.required {
    border: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `<abbr>` element - it has dotted border as default style, so try:

```css
abbr {
 border: none; 
}
```

Comment: Should be `abbr .required` in order to only get required fields.

Comment: If that's desired it's need to be like that `abbr.required` (no space between)